# Dart Null Coalescing not returning default value

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, flutter

I have a list of staff 4 of whom are external consultants so they have no department in our Firebase Realtime Database.

In a FirebaseAnimatedList I am listing staff in an employee directory.

In my model I am trying to deal with those null values to suppress the error:

> A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget. flutter:
>   'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart': flutter: Failed assertion:
>   line 253 pos 10: 'data != null'

I have used the following to no avail:

```
department = snapshot.value['department'] ?? 'Managment',

department = snapshot.value['department'] ??= 'Managment',

department = snapshot.value['department']
            ? snapshot.value['department']
            : 'Management',
```

Any suggestions for this Flutter beginner is appreciated.

UPDATED with solution -- this is my entire model:

```
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';

class Staff {
  String key;
  String avatar;
  String badge;
  int dbId;
  String department;
  String directLine;
  String email;
  String extension;
  String firstName;
  bool isOnline;
  String lastName;
  String location;
  String name;
  String status;
  String title;
  String uid;

  Staff(
      this.key,
      this.avatar,
      this.badge,
      this.dbId,
      this.department,
      this.directLine,
      this.email,
      this.extension,
      this.firstName,
      this.isOnline,
      this.lastName,
      this.location,
      this.name,
      this.status,
      this.title,
      this.uid);

  Staff.fromSnapshot(DataSnapshot snapshot)
      : key = snapshot.key,
        avatar = "https://files.uaminc.com/images/avatars/" +
            snapshot.value['avatar'],
        badge = snapshot.value['badge'],
        dbId = snapshot.value['dbId'],
        department = snapshot.value.containsKey('department')
            ? snapshot.value['department']
            : 'Management',
        directLine = snapshot.value['directLine'],
        email = snapshot.value['email'],
        extension = snapshot.value['extension'],
        firstName = snapshot.value['firstName'],
        isOnline = snapshot.value['isOnline'],
        lastName = snapshot.value['lastName'],
        location = snapshot.value['location'],
        name = snapshot.value['name'],
        status = snapshot.value['status'],
        title = snapshot.value.containsKey('title')
            ? snapshot.value['title']
            : 'Management',
        uid = snapshot.value['uid'];

  toJson() {
    return {
      "key": key,
      "avatar": avatar,
      "badge": badge,
      "dbId": dbId,
      "department": department,
      "directLine": directLine,
      "email": email,
      "extension": extension,
      "firstName": firstName,
      "isOnline": isOnline,
      "lastName": lastName,
      "location": location,
      "name": name,
      "status": status,
      "title": title,
      "uid": uid,
    };
  } // end method
}
```

Comment: The string being null does not mean that snapshot value is nil. Could you try: if snapshot.value['department'] == '' { department = 'Management' } else { department = snapshot.value['department'] ?? 'Managment' }

Comment: sorry, new here. I have edited the question to show the fromSnapshot method ... I don't know how to integrate your answer

Comment: Could you show line 253 and the complete function in which it is ? A non-null String must be provided to a Text widget. flutter: 'package:flutter/src/widgets/text.dart': flutter: Failed assertion: line 253 pos 10: 'data != null'

Comment: edited question to add everything ... SORRY for my naiveté

Comment: Could you add a print statement.   static String getDepartment(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
print(snapshot).  to see exactly what you get.

Comment: see above and THANKS!!!!

Comment: Sorry, I should have asked to print snapshot.value

Comment: that print(snaphot.value) led me to the solution (containsKey). Thanks!!!

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Good continuation.